# When is it appropriate to use a deprecated method in android

Tags: android, coding-style

I was about to use the android class Sound Pool when I noticed it has become deprecated. Should I try to find the newest version every-time or just use the deprecated method?

Comment: Being deprecated generally means there's an alternative that has replaced it, and it's been done for a good reason. I'd say use the newer version unless there's a very specific reason not to :)

Comment: The SoundPool class wasn't deprecated, just the constructor.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool(int, int, int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real answer? Never.

It is deprecated for a reason. Deprecated methods are methods that will not be updated and may cease to be supported at all. Try to find the newest way of doing what you want to do with the most up-to-date API.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

There is a better way to do it, but that doesn't mean you *cant do it*. You are probably safe, but you will have to keep an eye on performance, especially for android.